# How can I have several statements inside a structural directive on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new to Angular 2 and haven't worked front end before. So I'm not sure how to write a template structural directives. I need to translate this from `ejs/angular 1 to Angular 2`

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    <% var classes = item.columns[i].fields.skin.indexOf("sign-in") > -1 ? "sign-in" : "" %>
       <div class="dropdown menu-standout desktop <%= classes %>">
           <a><%= item.columns[i].fields.title %></a>
       </div>
}
```

My best guess was this, but I'm sure I can't have curly brackets twice inside `ngFor`. Any help?

```
<li *ngFor="let column of item.columns">
    {{var classes = column.fields.skin.indexOf("sign-in") > -1 ? "sign-in":""}}
    <div class="dropdown menu-standout desktop" {{ classes }}>
        <a>{{column.fields.title}}</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the syntax by writing an extra function

```
<li *ngFor="let column of item[0].fields.columns">
    <div class="dropdown menu-standout desktop {{ checkIndex(column) }}" > 
        <a>{{column.fields.title}}</a>
    </div>
</li>   

export class PageDropdownComponent {
    constructor() {}

    checkIndex(classes:any) {
        return classes.fields.skin.indexOf("sign-in") > -1 ? "sign-in" : "";
    }
```

Thanks everyone else for the help, it was useful for understanding the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You `can not have binding assignment in template interpolation directive`.
So, it should be like this

```
{{column.fields.skin.indexOf("sign-in") > -1 ? "sign-in":""}}
```

You `can not declared variable inside interpolation directive`

Remove the `var classes =` part from template otherwise it will template parse error.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add a class dynamically, so try this :

```
<li *ngFor="let column of item.columns">

    <div  [class.active] = "isActive = 'column.fields.skin.indexOf("sign-in") > -1 ? "sign-in":"" ' " class="dropdown menu-standout desktop"> 
        <a>{{column.fields.title}}</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

it is not good practice to have js code in your view.

in your component

```
export class MyComponent {

isActive: boolean = false;
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting error if I use this code, it says. Unexpected closing tag "div"